# how to compare multiple views using if condition

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am making Sign Up form in which i am using four linear layouts and using View i am showing the three linear Layouts as next windows. But i want to over ride 
    onBackPressed(){}
for this how can i compare, how will i deduct the current layout and how can i compare remaining layouts. here is my xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/PD"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="FirstName*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="LastName*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Email*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Password*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="ConfirmPassword*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:hint="DateofBirth*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Gender*" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/next"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:onClick="Next"
                    android:text="NEXT" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/PD1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="FirstName1*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="LastName1*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Email1*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Password1*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="ConfirmPassword1*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:hint="DateofBirth1*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Gender1*" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/next2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:onClick="Next2"
                    android:text="NEXT" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/PD1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="FirstName2*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="LastName2*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Email2*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Password2*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="ConfirmPassword2*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:hint="DateofBirth2*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FN"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Gender2*" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/next"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:onClick="Next3"
                    android:text="NEXT" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    View v;
    LinearLayout l1,l2,l3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        l3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout3);
    }
    public void Next(View v) {
        v = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.i("IN 1st WIndow", "got it");
        v = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    public void Next2(View v){
        v = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.i("IN 2nd WIndow", "got it");
        v = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout3);
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    public void Next3(View v){
        v = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.i("IN 3rd WIndow", "got it");
        v = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout3);
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(l3.getVisibility == View.VISIBLE){
        l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else if(l2.getVisibility == View.VISIBLE){
        l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
    super.onBackPressed();
   }
}
```

Please help me in this issue. I am sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(LL3.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        LL3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        LL2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else if(LL2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        LL2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        LL1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

get **LL1, LL2, LL3** in your `onCreate()`:

```
LL1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
LL2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
LL3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout3);
```

Comment: But getVisibility() is a method of Int only na @Archie.bpgc.. as i am getting error like "getVisibility cannot be resolved or is not a field" in if loop. Out side of IF loop it is ok..

Comment: public void onBackPressed() {
  if(l3.getVisibility == View.VISIBLE){
         l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }else if(l2.getVisibility == View.VISIBLE){
         l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }else{
     super.onBackPressed();
     }
 } In oncreate i instantiated the l1,l2,l3. In this the error occurred at getVisibility. which is shown in previous post

Comment: Hey it should be `getVisibility()` it is a method. My bad >.<

Comment: i am sorry buddy.. After replacing the (l3.getVisibility == VIEW.VISIBLE) with (l3.getVisibility() == VIEW.VISIBLE). I got the code working. Thanks a lot buddy.....

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this could work:

```
private int mPosition = 0; 
private View[] mPages;     // instantiate and populate this in onCreate

private void showNext() {
  show(false, mPages[mPosition]);
  show(true, mPages[++mPosition]);
}

private void showPrevious() {
  show(false, mPages[mPosition]);
  show(true, mPages[--mPosition]);
}

@Override 
public void onBackPressed() {
  showPrevious();
}

private static void show(final boolean show, final View view) {
  final int visibility = show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
  view.setVisibility(visibility);
}
```

Of course you'd have to ensure `mPosition` is properly bound.

Comment: Boss i am unable to use your code. I am new to android. will you explain how to use @curtisLoew

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtFirstName1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="FirstName*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtLastName1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="LastName*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtEmail1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:hint="Email*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtPassword1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="Password*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtConfirmPassword1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="ConfirmPassword*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtDateOfBirth1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:hint="DateofBirth*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtGender1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Gender*" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtFirstName2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="FirstName*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtLastName2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="LastName*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtEmail2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:hint="Email*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtPassword2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="Password*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtConfirmPassword2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="ConfirmPassword*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtDateOfBirth2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:hint="DateofBirth*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtGender2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Gender*" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtFirstName3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="FirstName*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtLastName3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="LastName*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtEmail3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:hint="Email*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtPassword3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="Password*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtConfirmPassword3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="ConfirmPassword*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtDateOfBirth3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:hint="DateofBirth*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtGender3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Gender*" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNextFinish"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private LinearLayout layout1;
    private LinearLayout layout2;
    private LinearLayout layout3;

    private EditText edtFirstName1;
    private EditText edtLastName1;
    private EditText edtEmail1;
    private EditText edtPassword1;
    private EditText edtConfirmPassword1;
    private EditText edtDateOfBirth1;
    private EditText edtGender1;

    private EditText edtFirstName2;
    private EditText edtLastName2;
    private EditText edtEmail2;
    private EditText edtPassword2;
    private EditText edtConfirmPassword2;
    private EditText edtDateOfBirth2;
    private EditText edtGender2;

    private EditText edtFirstName3;
    private EditText edtLastName3;
    private EditText edtEmail3;
    private EditText edtPassword3;
    private EditText edtConfirmPassword3;
    private EditText edtDateOfBirth3;
    private EditText edtGender3;

    private Button btnNextFinish;

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layout1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        layout2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        layout3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout3);
        btnNextFinish = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNextFinish);

        edtFirstName1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtFirstName1);
        edtLastName1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtLastName1);
        edtEmail1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtEmail1);
        edtPassword1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword1);
        edtConfirmPassword1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtConfirmPassword1);
        edtDateOfBirth1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtDateOfBirth1);
        edtGender1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtGender1);

        edtFirstName2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtFirstName2);
        edtLastName2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtLastName2);
        edtEmail2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtEmail2);
        edtPassword2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword2);
        edtConfirmPassword2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtConfirmPassword2);
        edtDateOfBirth2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtDateOfBirth2);
        edtGender2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtGender2);

        edtFirstName3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtFirstName3);
        edtLastName3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtLastName3);
        edtEmail3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtEmail3);
        edtPassword3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword3);
        edtConfirmPassword3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtConfirmPassword3);
        edtDateOfBirth3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtDateOfBirth3);
        edtGender3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtGender3);

        btnNextFinish = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNextFinish);
        btnNextFinish.setText("Next");
        btnNextFinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean isValidate=true;

                if(layout1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    if (edtFirstName1.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtFirstName1.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }
                    if (edtLastName1.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtLastName1.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }
                    if (edtPassword1.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtPassword1.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    } else if (!edtConfirmPassword1.getText().toString().trim().equals(edtPassword1.getText().toString().trim())) {
                        edtConfirmPassword1.setError("Invalid Confirm Password");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }

                    if (edtDateOfBirth1.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtDateOfBirth1.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }

                    if (edtEmail1.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtEmail1.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    } else if (!emailValidator(edtEmail1.getText().toString().trim())) {
                        edtPassword2.setError("Invalid Email");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }

                    if (edtGender1.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtGender1.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }

                    if (isValidate) {
                        layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        layout3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map1.put("FirstName", edtFirstName1.getText().toString());
                        map1.put("LastName", edtLastName1.getText().toString());
                        map1.put("Email", edtEmail1.getText().toString());
                        map1.put("Password", edtPassword1.getText().toString());
                        map1.put("DateOfBirth", edtDateOfBirth1.getText().toString());
                        map1.put("Gender", edtGender1.getText().toString());
                        data.add(0, map1);
                    }
                }else if(layout2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    if (edtFirstName2.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtFirstName2.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }
                    if (edtLastName2.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtLastName2.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }
                    if (edtPassword2.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtPassword2.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    } else if (!edtConfirmPassword2.getText().toString().trim().equals(edtPassword2.getText().toString().trim())) {
                        edtConfirmPassword2.setError("Invalid Confirm Password");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }

                    if (edtDateOfBirth2.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtDateOfBirth2.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }

                    if (edtEmail2.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtEmail2.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    } else if (!emailValidator(edtEmail2.getText().toString().trim())) {
                        edtPassword2.setError("Invalid Email");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }

                    if (edtGender2.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtGender2.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }

                    if (isValidate) {
                        layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map2.put("FirstName", edtFirstName2.getText().toString());
                        map2.put("LastName", edtLastName2.getText().toString());
                        map2.put("Email", edtEmail2.getText().toString());
                        map2.put("Password", edtPassword2.getText().toString());
                        map2.put("DateOfBirth", edtDateOfBirth2.getText().toString());
                        map2.put("Gender", edtGender2.getText().toString());
                        data.add(1, map2);
                        btnNextFinish.setText("Finish");
                    }
                }else{
                    if (edtFirstName3.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtFirstName3.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }
                    if (edtLastName3.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtLastName3.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }
                    if (edtPassword3.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtPassword3.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    } else if (!edtConfirmPassword3.getText().toString().trim().equals(edtPassword3.getText().toString().trim())) {
                        edtConfirmPassword3.setError("Invalid Confirm Password");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }

                    if (edtDateOfBirth3.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtDateOfBirth3.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }

                    if (edtEmail3.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtEmail3.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    } else if (!emailValidator(edtEmail3.getText().toString().trim())) {
                        edtPassword3.setError("Invalid Email");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }

                    if (edtGender3.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                        edtGender3.setError("Value Required");
                        isValidate = false;
                    }

                    if (isValidate) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map3.put("FirstName", edtFirstName3.getText().toString());
                        map3.put("LastName", edtLastName3.getText().toString());
                        map3.put("Email", edtEmail3.getText().toString());
                        map3.put("Password", edtPassword3.getText().toString());
                        map3.put("DateOfBirth", edtDateOfBirth3.getText().toString());
                        map3.put("Gender", edtGender3.getText().toString());
                        data.add(2, map3);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(layout3.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layout3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnNextFinish.setText("Next");
        }else if(layout2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layout3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnNextFinish.setText("Next");
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public boolean emailValidator(final String mailAddress) {
        Pattern pattern;
        Matcher matcher;
        final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
        pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(mailAddress);
        return matcher.matches();

    }

}
```